# CSV from text file using node.js (CSV package)

Tags: javascript, node.js, export-to-csv

I have a file in the format of "data1,data2".

For example:
France,Paris
United Kingdom, London
Germany, Berlin
etc.. etc..

I want to convert this into CSV and I use the csv package in node.js. 
The code I used is:

```
csv()
.from(fs.createReadStream('./test.txt'))
.to(fs.createWriteStream('./file.csv'))
```

When I open file.csv in excel I have an output of 1 column and as many rows as the data. However I want to create two different columns.

I didn't find any example of how to do so on the net. Any advice/help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want to split your data first, as your string isn't ready for CSV data yet.

My expected output would be:
Paris, France
London, United Kingdom

Your input data seems weird to me, as each record/row is seperated by a line, and each column is seperated by a comma. A weird way to group two things with a comma between them. Just a question to you to verify that is really your input data.

EDIT1: The easiest way is to get a better input.
Rows are seperated by lines, and columns are seperated by comma's. Problem is with you current data, there are 'spaces' with different meanings. One to seperate words like 'United' and 'Kingdom'. And spaces to seperate rows/columns(depending on how you look at it).

You can change to delimiters to something else. For example, comma's for colmuns, and ; for rows/records.

```
.from(fs.createReadStream('./test.txt'), { delimiter: ',', escape: ';' })
```

I guess this would work on:
France,Paris;United Kingdom,London;Belgium,Brussel; etc.

http://www.adaltas.com/projects/node-csv/from.html

Comment: it is my input data but I created this when I was creating the .txt file. however I can create any kind of input. Like the one you suggested. If I do so, how can this new format help me? Thanks